# как проверить введение данные в telegram bot aiмogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

как сверить верность введенных данных с имеющимися в списке. ps хочу сделать личный словарь для проверки слов. к примеру написал "кошка", если оно есть в списке то бот пишет "ты прав"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor

bot = Bot('token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

list = ['кошка', 'собака']

@dp.message_handler()
async def handler(msg: types.Message):
    text = msg.text.lower()
    if text in list:
        await msg.answer('ты прав')
    else:
        await msg.answer('ты НЕ прав!')

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```